# Python version updated in Raspberry pi but not used when Installing OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, interpreter, raspberry-pi4

I installed python 3.9.0 in my raspberry pi following this guide https://raspberrytips.com/install-latest-python-raspberry-pi/. The base python version is 3.7.3 and following the above guides I changed to recognize the default version as 3.9.0.

Nevertheless, when I tried installing OpenCV I saw in the console that it will use the 3.7.3 interpreter. Do you know why?

When I type python --version it will print 3.9.0.

Any inputs are welcome.

Comment: **how** did you install OpenCV?

Comment: I installed open cv manually as pip was never succesfull in installing opencv. I followed the scripts in this link:
https://github.com/freedomwebtech/opencv2

When I run the following script for the make file it takes 3.7.3 into account and ignores 3.9.0: 
https://github.com/freedomwebtech/opencv2/blob/main/install3.sh

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: In my case and many other people's cases this does not work. From what I read this is because raspberry pi's are using arm processors and this causes problems for this reason I need to install opencv manually